# Django How do i Insert data without refreshing or reloading page

Tags: python, django

How to do in django to return with the current page after the user insert their data (request.post)

scenario:

*If the teacher insert the grades of their students, the current page will reload or refresh*.

I don't know if I can achieve it by using redirect.

```
def grades(request):
    V_insert_data = StudentSubjectGrade(
          ...
    )
  V_insert_data.save()

  //redirect the same page


def teacher(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        raise Http404('Only POSTs are allowed')
    try:
         ......
         return render(request, 'Homepage/index.html')
    except EmployeeUser.DoesNotExist:
        messages.warning(request, 'Your Username and password are Incorrect.')
        ….
    return render(request, 'Homepage/TeacherLogin.html')
```

urls.py

```
path('teacher/', Homepage.views.teacher, name='teacher'),
path('grades/', Homepage.views.grades, name='grades'),
```

this is the error i get

[image]

**UPDATE**

when I change my

```
  response = redirect(teacher)
  return response
```

to this

```
return redirect(reverse('teacher'))
```

i get the same result

**UPDATE** again

when I tried this

```
def grades(request):
    V_insert_data = StudentSubjectGrade(
          ...
    )
  V_insert_data.save()
return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)
```

I get this error

[image]

ive already clear my cookies but still this error appear

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve here. But the error you are getting is because you are sending a `GET` request to the view and from the view you have specified if the `requests.method` is other than `POST` then you are raising `Http404` error.

Comment: what I am trying to achieve mr @mohammedwazeem is if the teacher insert the grades of the students the current page will reload only

Answer (score 4):

If you want to redirect to the same page after the form successfully submitted return `HttpResponseRedirect`. Let me give a sample view here

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def grades(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # do your stuff here (saving data to db)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)
    return render(request, template, {'form': your_form})
```

Comment: how about in my def grades(request):?

Comment: You can return `HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)` if you want a view to be redirected to the same page after a form submission or whatever.

Comment: why you apply  HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info) under def teacher(request):?

Comment: you didn't get my question mr @mohammed wazeem , I said when the teacher submit the student grades it will redirect in to the same page, I think the logic here is in the """def grades(request):""" not in ""def teacher(request):""

Comment: What about now. I thought you are trying to achieve redirection in teacher view. But Anyway your question is how to redirect to the same page after a form submission. So you can use `HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)` in case of function based view. And also don't forget to check the request method before processing it

Comment: @Mary The problem is that you have to properly differentiate get and post requests to that view. return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info) will try a get requet to that same page. Please check my answer I have updated it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209721/discussion-between-mary-and-mohammed-wazeem).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209743/discussion-between-mohammed-wazeem-and-mary).

Answer (score 0):

```
def grades(request):
    V_insert_data = StudentSubjectGrade(
          ...
    )
  V_insert_data.save()

  return redirect(reverse('teacher'))


def teacher(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
             ......
             return render(request, 'Homepage/index.html')
        except EmployeeUser.DoesNotExist:
            messages.warning(request, 'Your Username and password are Incorrect.')
            ….
    return render(request, 'Homepage/TeacherLogin.html')
```

Comment: okay i think i caught your error and that is in your view function let me edit my answer

Comment: This is not recommended to change request.method != 'POST':

Comment: becasuse if the teacher login their account this error will appear

Comment: but if you are redirect to the teacher page it will always GET request and it always throw  this error

Comment: Yes, that is why I asked here Django return current page after form submit.. because I don't know how if the teacher insert the student grades the page will refresh or reload

Comment: https://www.botreetechnologies.com/blog/django-user-groups-and-permission